# Redirect a spring application behind reversy proxy lose flash attributes

Tags: spring, redirect, proxy

My applications redirects after POST operation some information to the GET controller but lose the information when using with Apache and reverse proxy. When I do this operation without the reverse proxy in the middle everything works fine. Some ideas?

```
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    @RequestMapping(value = "aCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String category(@RequestParam("aCategoryName") String name, Model model, RedirectAttributes attr,
                        HttpServletRequest request) {

                String redirect = "redirect:" + "http://localhost:8080/aCategory";
                aService.saveACategory(name);
                attr.addFlashAttribute("aCategoryName", name);
                return redirect;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "aCategory", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String appCategory(Model model, Principal principal) {
        String name = principal.getName(); // get logged in username
        model.addAttribute("username", name);
        return "aCategory";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your cluster configuration and session replication configuration. Because FlashAttributes are first stored in a session temporarily before adding it to the model map to display it on the redirected view. So if your cluster is not well configured for proper session replication then your FlashAttribute might be lost when request is served by another cluster than where the FlashAttribute is actually stored in session.

For further details you can refer my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489603/flashattributes-are-not-working-properly-when-application-deployed-on-a-clustere).

Hope this helps you. Cheers.