# Spring MVC flash attributes Amazon EC2 Apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, mod-proxy

I'm using Spring MVC 4.1.6.RELEASE version for my project. I have couple of flash attributes for different scenarios on login, register and forgot password pages which are accessed prior to user logging in. The application runs perfectly fine on my localhost which is a mac with Wildfly 8.2 version.

**The Problem:**
I have created an Amazon EC2 instance with RHEL version 7 (64-bit) and installed and configured the exact version of Wildfly with same JDK. None of the flash attributes show up for register and forgot password scenarios. However, any form submission errors on the same pages show up just fine. Another weird thing to note is, once logged in, any and all flash messages show up just fine.

**Research:**
This is the closest issue I have found which seems to be "//" error and I have already made sure that is not the case:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1072604

Any guidance is much appreciated!

**Update:**
The one difference between my local and Amazon setup is Apache. I have setup Apache on amazon ec2. Hopefully someone can throw some light as I'm still at loss.

**Update 2:**
After updating I started researching with Apache and found the issue (see link below) which is exactly what my issue is BUT I'm not sure how to solve mine, yet.

[Spring's flashAttributes don't work behind a reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367531/springs-flashattributes-dont-work-behind-a-reverse-proxy)

**Update 3:**
After more trial and errors I figured out that flash attributes work just fine if I access the website using the static-ip like http:// xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/context-root/forgot-password but doesn't work when i use the domain name - http:// www.domainname.com/context-root/forgot-password.

I have provided my existing configuration. Any mod_proxy experts, please help.

**Hosting:**
2 A records

@    12.34.56.789 -- this is the static ip for Amazon EC2

www  12.34.56.789 -- this is the static ip for Amazon EC2

**Apache Configuration**

/etc/apache/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 111.22.33.44 # this is local address of ec2.
ProxyPreserveHost On   
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>  
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>   

ProxyPass /context-root http://111.22.33.44:8080/<context-root>/
ProxyPassReverse /context-root http://111.22.33.44:8080/<context-root>/

ProxyPass / http://111.22.33.44:8080/<context-root>/
ProxyPassReverse / http://111.22.33.44:8080/<context-root>/
</VirtualHost>
```

**Wildfly Configuration: standalone.xml**

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="unsecure">
        <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
    </interface>
    <interface name="external">
        <nic name="eth0"/>
    </interface>
</interfaces>

<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="external" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="external" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" interface="external" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" interface="external" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" interface="external" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

**Headers as requested by Brian**

**These are the headers when i use static ip, flash attributes work in this scenario**

```
Response Headers

Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate  
Connection  keep-alive  
Content-Language    en-US  
Content-Length  0  
Date    **removed**  
Expires 0  
Location    http:// 12.34.56.789:8080/context-root/forgot  
Pragma  no-cache  
Server  WildFly/8  
X-Powered-By    Undertow/1  
x-content-type-options  nosniff  
x-frame-options DENY  
x-xss-protection    1; mode=block

Request Headers

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate  
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5  
Connection  keep-alive  
Cookie  JSESSIONID=pH25lMW0Rg3HKK1iXxVKIl1O.ip-111-22-33-44   
Host    12.34.56.789:8080  
Referer http:// 12.34.56.789:8080/context-root/forgot  
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1  
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0)   
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0

Request Headers from upload stream

Content-Length  92  
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

**These are the headers when i use domain name, flash attributes don't work**

```
Response Headers   
Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate  
Connection  Keep-Alive  
Content-Language    en-US  
Content-Length  0  
Date    **removed**  
Expires 0  
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=100  
Location    http:// www.domain-name/context-root/forgot  
Pragma  no-cache  
Server  WildFly/8  
X-Powered-By    Undertow/1  
x-content-type-options  nosniff  
x-frame-options DENY  
x-xss-protection    1; mode=block  

Request Headers  
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8  
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate  
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5  
Connection  keep-alive  
Cookie  JSESSIONID=4-DUMB5f1U7eTDcNePYUAy8c.ip-111-22-33-44  
Host    www.domain-name  
Referer http:// www.domain-name/context-root/forgot  
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests   1  
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:49.0)  Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0

Request Headers from upload stream  
Content-Length  92  
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Can you show the request/response headers? If this works when the IP is used but not the domain name, maybe the Cookie set by the server is on the wrong domain? If the session cookie is not sent, the server can't tie the request to an existing session (and that's where Spring is looking for flash information).

Comment: @BrianClozel Thank you for responding and closing my spring JIRA ticket. I have updated with headers. I have replaced my actual static ip with fake ip. Please note - 12.34.56.789 is the static ip and 111-22-33-44 is the ip of amazon ec2 box that gets appended to the cookie and thats the ip I had to use in apache configuration to make it work.

Comment: @BrianClozel please suggest if this is a bug or I have missed something.